# Shorten jquery code

Tags: jquery

I want to apply the same fuction to diffrent classes. Is there a way to make this code shorter?

```
jQuery('.class1').after("<p>text</p>");
jQuery('.class2').after("<p>text</p>");
jQuery('.class3').after("<p>text</p>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
jQuery('.class1, .class2, .class3').after("<p>text</p>");
```

[Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
jQuery('.class' + i).after("<p>text</p>");
```

or:

```
jQuery('.class1,.class2,.class3').after("<p>text</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like following.

```
jQuery('[class^="class"]').after("<p>text</p>");
```